# How to combine my own DataDource and BoundaryCallback?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-room, paging

I create application based on the Database + Network paging and GitHub rest api.
Using various tutorials, I came to the conclusion that when creating the LivePagedListBuilder in ViewModel, I must pass my query retrieving data from Room, to make it works then with BoundaryCallback.
This query in my code looks like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * from repositories_table ORDER BY name DESC")
    fun getPagedRepos(): DataSource.Factory<Int,Repository>
```

and its equivalent in the repository:

```
fun getPagedRepos(): DataSource.Factory<Int, Repository> {
    return repositoriesDao.getPagedRepos()
}
```

However I would like to combine this with my **own** DataSource, not default one, which would also work with retrofitting data fetching.
Below are the relevant parts of my application:

**DataSource**

```
class ReposDataSource(private val contactsRepository: ContactsRepository,
                        private val scope: CoroutineScope, application: Application): PageKeyedDataSource<Int, Repository>() {

private var supervisorJob = SupervisorJob()

private val PREFS_NAME = "Paging"

private val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = application.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

override fun loadInitial(
    params: LoadInitialParams<Int>,
    callback: LoadInitialCallback<Int, Repository>
) {
    Log.i("RepoBoundaryCallback", "initialTriggered")
    val currentPage = 1
    val nextPage = currentPage + 1

    executeQuery(currentPage, params.requestedLoadSize) {
        callback.onResult(it, null, nextPage)
    }
}

override fun loadAfter(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, Repository>) {

    val currentPage = params.key
    val nextPage = currentPage + 1

    executeQuery(currentPage, params.requestedLoadSize) {
        callback.onResult(it, nextPage)
    }
}

override fun invalidate() {
    super.invalidate()
    supervisorJob.cancelChildren()
}

private fun executeQuery(page: Int, perPage: Int, callback: (List<Repository>) -> Unit) {
    scope.launch(getJobErrorHandler() + supervisorJob) {
        savePage("current_page", page)
        val repos = contactsRepository.fetchPagedRepos(page, perPage)
        callback(repos)
    }
}

private fun getJobErrorHandler() = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e ->
    Log.e(ReposDataSource::class.java.simpleName, "An error happened: $e")
}

private fun savePage(KEY_NAME: String, value: Int){
    Log.i("RepoBoundaryCallback", value.toString())
    val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPref.edit()
    editor.putInt(KEY_NAME, value)
    editor.commit()
}
```

}

**BoundaryCallback**

```
class RepoBoundaryCallback (val repository: ContactsRepository, application: Application) :
PagedList.BoundaryCallback<Repository?>() {


private var callbackJob = Job()

private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(
    callbackJob + Dispatchers.Main )

private val PREFS_NAME = "Paging"

private val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = application.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

override fun onZeroItemsLoaded() {
    Log.i("RepoBoundaryCallback", "onzeroitemstriggered")
    super.onZeroItemsLoaded()
    fetchUsers(1)
}

override fun onItemAtEndLoaded(itemAtEnd: Repository) {
    Log.i("RepoBoundaryCallback", "onitematendriggered")
    super.onItemAtEndLoaded(itemAtEnd)
    fetchUsers(getCurrentPage("current_page"))
}

private fun fetchUsers(page: Int) {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        try {
            var newRepos = RepoApi.retrofitService.fetchRepos(page)
            insertRepoToDb(newRepos)
        }
        catch (e: Exception){
            Log.i("RepoBoundaryCallback", e.toString())
        }
    }
}

 private suspend fun insertRepoToDb(reposList: List<Repository>){
    reposList.forEach{repository.insertRepo(it)}
}

private fun getCurrentPage(KEY_NAME: String): Int{
    return sharedPref.getInt(KEY_NAME, 0)
}
```

}

**Api query**

```
interface RepoApiService {
@GET("/orgs/google/repos")
suspend fun fetchRepos(@Query("page") page: Int,
                       @Query("per_page") perPage: Int = 15): List<Repository>
```

}

**ViewModel**

```
class RepositoryViewModel (application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

companion object{
    private const val TAG = "RepositoryViewModel"
}

//var reposList: LiveData<PagedList<Repository>>

private var repoBoundaryCallback: RepoBoundaryCallback? = null

var reposList: LiveData<PagedList<Repository>>? = null

private val repository: ContactsRepository

private var viewModelJob = Job()

private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(
    viewModelJob + Dispatchers.Main )

init {
    val contactsDao = ContactsRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).contactsDao()
    val contactsExtrasDao = ContactsRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).contactsExtrasDao()
    val repositoriesDao = ContactsRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).repositoriesDao()
    val service = RepoApi.retrofitService
    repository = ContactsRepository(contactsDao, contactsExtrasDao, repositoriesDao, service)
    initializedPagedListBuilder(application)
}


private fun initializedPagedListBuilder(application: Application) {
    repoBoundaryCallback = RepoBoundaryCallback(
        repository, application
    )

    val pagedListConfig = PagedList.Config.Builder()
        //.setPrefetchDistance(5)
        //.setInitialLoadSizeHint(20)
        .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
        .setPageSize(15).build()

    reposList = LivePagedListBuilder(
        repository.getPagedRepos(),
        pagedListConfig
    ).setBoundaryCallback(repoBoundaryCallback).build()
}


override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    viewModelJob.cancel()
}
}
```

In addition, I save the relevant pages in SharedPreferences in the DataSource to then use it in the corresponding BoundaryCallback functions.
So how do you link your own DataSource to BoundaryCallback with Room and Retrofit? I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`BoundaryCallback` is responsible for triggering invalidation on your current generation of `DataSource`. With `DataSource.Factory` generated by Room, this is automatically handled for you as Room will invalidate any `DataSource` it generates that is affected by writes to DB. This is why a `DataSource.Factory` is necessary over a single `DataSource`. Paging sees a single instance of `DataSource` as a "snapshot" of static data. If the data it's supposed to be loading changes in any way you must call `DataSource.invalidate()` to allow `DataSource.Factory` to generate a new up-to-date snapshot.

Since you're implementing your own `DataSource`, you'll also need to implement a `DataSource.Factory` and call `invalidate()` from your `BoundaryCallback` (doesn't necessarily need to be in the same class, but `invalidate()` must be triggered when your `BoundaryCallback` writes updates).